# Buttons in JQGrid

Tags: servlets, jqgrid

I have added multiple buttons in JQGrid.I want to display different set of data when i click on each button.So How to check in Servlet that which button is clicked.

```
        //jsp page

      .navButtonAdd('#page',{
                        caption:"By Source IP",
                        buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
                        onClickButton: function(){
                            $('#jQGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam',     
              {postData:{KeyName:"IP"}}).trigger('JQGridServlet',[{page:1}]);   
                            },
                        id:"IP",
                        }

 //Servlet Page
 String KeyName=request.getParameter("KeyName");
            System.out.println(KeyName);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button event set set a `postData` parameter in the jqGrid and ask it to reload.  This extra parameter would tell your server side code to change data sets.

Ex:
 Button event code:

```
...
$('#gridName').jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { KeyName: KeyValue}}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1}]);
....
```

Controller/Servlet:

```
public ActionResult SearchGetGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string filters, string KeyName)
{
 if (KeyName == someValue { //change datasets, etc...
```

Comment: .navButtonAdd('#page',{
               caption:"By Source IP",
               buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
                id:"IP",
                }                                                                  above is my code for jqgrid,where should i add your code.

Comment: If you look at the documentation you would add it inside the onClickButton parameter. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons

Comment: It's just reloading the grid. It is giving null value for KeyName in Servlet.

Comment: And you are setting KeyName to somthing? Does KeyName match on the setGridParam and on the Servlet? After you set the param you can use the `getGridParam` to examine the property set on the grid as well.

Comment: //////.jsp page                                                                                                            .navButtonAdd('#page',{
               caption:"By Source IP",
               onClickButton: function(){
                $('#jQGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam',{postData:{KeyName:"submit"}}).trigger('JQGridServlet',[{page:1}]); 
               },id:"IP",
                        //Servlet Page                                                       String KeyName=request.getParameter("KeyName");
                System.out.println(KeyName);

Comment: Can you edit your orginal post if you are trying to show something? Plus I used the `getGridParam` as a method for you to check the parameter you set AFTER the button is clicked.  In the `onClickButton` you are SETTING a jqGrid parameter via `setGridParam`, then you trigger a reload and that parameter is passed to the Servlet.  You would also be able to see the parameter included as part of the POST via Firebug (or it's equiv).

Comment: @abhijit Did you get your problem fixed? Did this help? If so please mark as correct